# How can I use a single gmail address in a MTA (Mail Transfer Application)?

Tags: django, email, smtp

I would like to allow users to send automated emails from a dedicated email address (automated_alerts@my-domain.com).

However, in the scripts, I don't want to give users access to the credentials.json so that they can modify the scope. I don't want to use a service that I need to pay for such as Amazon SES.

I have looked into resources at the following links below, but  I want users to simply specify an html body, any attachments, and the recipients and then forward this on to the MTA. If a user leaves the company, the automated emails should not fail when the user's email gets closed out. The script would just need to get moved to a different server's cron or whatever.

Is there an easy way to do this? I am happy to use Django also, but would prefer to avoid using SES and having to pay to send internal company emails:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/
- https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Why would users have access to credentials? Why would they have access to the code at all?

Comment: They're all developers within the same company. Let's say you have an automated email you want to send to a select group of users on a consistent basis, how do you do this without tying the sending of the email to the users account?

Comment: I don't understand why it would be tied to a user's account at all. It should be done by the Django server itself, which you could connect to any mail server you want.

Comment: Great @DanielRoseman! So what does that workflow look like when "the Django server is doing the work itself?" Say I'm a developer within the company and I want to send or schedule automated emails. Let's use this trivial example: Subject="Hello, it is {}".format(todays_date). Body={some data} What is the workflow for the user to (1) generate the data & subject; (2) schedule or send the email via Cron or Airflow? (3) How can I only allow users to send emails via the shared address once they prove they are who they say they are (using LDAP preferably)? I know his is a lot- I appreciate your help